# Android Java JsonObject put only last value

Tags: java, android, json

im been working apps with booking system, and i have problem with generate json and send it to server. the server catch this json

```
    "buy":{  
      "583":[  
         {  
            "title":"Mr",
            "nama_depan":"Mulia Rifai Aroyan",
            "nama_belakang":"",
            "tanggal_lahir":"0000-0-0",
            "nationality":"Indonesia",
            "identitas":"identitas",
            "kelas_id":"254",
            "kelas":"B",
            "harga":"60000",
            "seat":""
         }
      ],
      "584":[  
         {  
            "title":"Mr",
            "nama_depan":"Mulia Rifai Aroyan",
            "nama_belakang":"",
            "tanggal_lahir":"0000-0-0",
            "nationality":"Indonesia",
            "identitas":"identitas",
            "kelas_id":"254",
            "kelas":"B",
            "harga":"60000",
            "seat":""
         }
      ]
   }
```

and i create generated json like this :

```
    final JSONObject buy_child = new JSONObject();
final JSONArray buy = new JSONArray();
final JSONObject detail = new JSONObject();
for (int i=0;i<list_id_content.size();i++)
{
    detail.put("title",gelar);
    detail.put("nama_depan",nama_depan);
    detail.put("nama_belakang",nama_belakang);
    detail.put("tanggal_lahir",tanggal_lahir);
    detail.put("nationality",nationality);
    detail.put("identitas",identitas);
    detail.put("kelas_id",id_event);
    detail.put("kelas",kelas);
    detail.put("harga",total_harga_pertiket);
    detail.put("seat","");
    buy.put(detail);
    buy_child.put(id_event_content2,buy);
}
```

but its seems only generate json with same value (the last value)

how can i generate json like that and get all the value inside the loop?

thanks

edited : if i put JSONObject detail = new JSONObject(); inside the loop, it will give me this

[image]

Comment: buy.put(detail); 
don't you think it should be in for loop braces

Comment: im edited the question sorry. @vikaskumar

Comment: Your JSON Array has the wrong format, You are creating JSON array with every JSON object, 583,584 should come under single JSON array, this is a bad practice you have to create another loop for this situation.

Comment: create new JsonObject for each iteration otherwise same data will be stored in each array with last values only. Also you should have some data structure where you must be storing the user booking data so you can get them in for loop with index not manually this will also result the same data

Comment: @farhana okee, il try contact others team to ask about this

Comment: what is list_id_content.size()  ? because loop  make 2 object of detail

Comment: @Adilhusen  [{total_harga_pertiket=100000, id_event_content=583, kelas=A, jumlah_tiket=2, harga=50000}, {total_harga_pertiket=60000, id_event_content=584, kelas=B, jumlah_tiket=1, harga=60000}] its just 2 array

Answer (score 0):

Put the `JSONObject detail = new JSONObject();` inside the for loop at the beginning.

Then put `buy.put(detail);` at the end of the loop (but inside).

You're only getting the last one right now because the buy.put is outside the for loop.

Comment: if i put JSONObject detail = new JSONObject(); inside the lopp, its get douplicate value , i update my question and give you a screenshot\

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
 final JSONObject buy_child = new JSONObject();
      final JSONArray buy;
        for (int i=0;i<list_id_content.size();i++)
        {
             buy= new JSONArray();
            final JSONObject detail = new JSONObject();

            detail.put("title",gelar);
            detail.put("nama_depan",nama_depan);
            detail.put("nama_belakang",nama_belakang);
            detail.put("tanggal_lahir",tanggal_lahir);
            detail.put("nationality",nationality);
            detail.put("identitas",identitas);
            detail.put("kelas_id",id_event);
            detail.put("kelas",kelas);
            detail.put("harga",total_harga_pertiket);
            detail.put("seat","");
            buy.put(detail);

        }
 buy_child.put(id_event_content2,buy);
```